# What does SIGUSR1 mean in "killall -SIGUSR1 tint2"

Tags: openbox, tint2

I want to use [tint2](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/) as my panel in an Openbox session.

The tint2 configuration file is ~/.config/tint2/tint2rc. The tint2 [configuration instructions](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Configure) have this:

> When you change the config file, the command line 'killall -SIGUSR1 tint2' will force tint2 to reload it.

What does

```
killall -SIGUSR1
```

do?

In other words, how does running `killall -SIGUSR1 tint2` cause `tint2rc` to be **reloaded**?

---

Edit: it appears that ~/.conkyrc can be reloaded the same way. From `man conky`:

> An  easy  way  to  force Conky to reload your ~/.conkyrc: "killall -SIGUSR1 conky". Saves you the trouble of having to kill and  then restart. You can now also do the same with SIGHUP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kill` command really send a signal to the process... it's a bit misnamed.

The command

```
killall -SIGxxx name
```

will send the "signal" `xxx` to the process with name "name". Process in Unix can receive and handle a set of signals to respond to external events. By default `kill` send the signal SIGTERM that has the (predefined) effect of gracefully kill the process. (the SIGKILL signal will kill the process "brutally", this is the reason that sometime you need to use the `killall -SIGKILL ...` command).

Some process have hardcoded meaning (for example: `HUP` is desconnection, etc. ) and are sometime sent by the kernel. `USR1` and `USR2` are user-definable signals.

You can even do that in scripts easily: if you put in a script the line

```
trap "echo TRAPPED" USR1
```

the script will print "TRAPPED" when you send the signal USR1 to it with the kill command.

So the answer to the last question is:

Evidently, the "tint2" program has code that, upon receiving the signal USR1, will reload its configuration file.

See for example http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7

Comment: Please see last line added as edit

Comment: _"Evidently, the "tint2" program has code that, upon receiving the signal USR2, will reload its configuration file."_ seems to be what is happening although `USR2` should be `USR1`.